# Custom UIbutton inside a nested UICollectionView cell does not get fired

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a main `UICollectionView` which contains a custom `header` and a custom cell. Inside the custom cell I have another `UICollectionView` with a custom cell in which there are three buttons (inside a stackView) that has added target as a `selector function` to it for `.touchUpInside` but when I touch the button it does not fire the selector function at all. `didSelectItemAt` function gets called on parent `UICollectionView` but not the nested one. If I comment out the parent `didSelectItemAt` nothing is called.

I have also set the nested collectionView delegate. Any idea what I should do to make it work would be much appreciated.

(I don't use storyboard)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Alf for my case the issue was related to auto-layout. Somehow the the inner collectionView was showing ok on the screen but as a hierarchy level the button was under the top layer. I gave a different bgColor to all layers (Views) and found out there is an issue with layout of nested collectionView

Answer (score 0):

Check that `view.isUserInteractionEnabled` is true for the parent view.

Comment: It is true. that's why `didSelectItemAt` gets called on the parent CollectionView

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your parent collection view's `.delaysContentTouches`, and if that doesn't work, try to `override hitTest` all the way down at your button's view level hierarchy and see if the touch reaches it.